# git submodules and detached HEAD

Tags: macos, git, git-submodules

So, I've been learning a bit more about git submodules, and everywhere that I read tells me that I end up with a detached HEAD after I add my submodule. This makes sense as I want my superproject to know specifically which commit should be used.  However, it isn't what I am seeing in practice (on Mac OS X).

Consider the following sequence of commands that create a quick repo (called sub) with a single file in it, and then adds that as a submodule to another repo called blah.

```
/tmp> git version 
git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
/tmp> git init sub
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/sub/.git/
/tmp> cd sub
/tmp/sub> touch a.txt
/tmp/sub> git add a.txt
/tmp/sub> git commit -m "add a file"
[master (root-commit) c527790] .
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 a.txt
/tmp/sub> cd ..
/tmp> git init blah
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/blah/.git/
/tmp> cd blah
/tmp/blah> git submodule add /tmp/sub sub
Cloning into 'sub'...
done.
/tmp/blah> cd sub
/tmp/blah/sub> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Why is the submodule on the master branch?  I would have expected it to say that it is not on a branch.  A bit more digging suggests that git is referencing the correct commit hash, but is somehow on the master branch, instead of a detached HEAD.

```sh
/tmp/blah/sub> cd ../../sub
/tmp/sub> git reflog
97b97b3 HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): add a file
/tmp/sub> cd ../blah
/tmp/blah> git submodule status
 97b97b349cfae8da490c2cad3b3f4fc3af6a53c7 sub (heads/master)
```

What am I missing?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this command:

```
git submodule add /tmp/sub sub
```

Results in a normal `clone` operation, so you end up on the `HEAD` of the master branch. However, if you examine the resulting commit, you'll see that `git` records the explicit commit hash in your repository.

From inside your `blah` repository:

```
$ git commit -m 'added submodule'
[master (root-commit) 13e36eb] added submodule
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 sub
$ git log --oneline
13e36eb added submodule
$ git cat-file -p 13e36eb
tree 5d205c2e2ce63d8087b3b6644e3ac183cd49c644
author Lars <lars@> 1363184265 -0400
committer Lars <lars@> 1363184265 -0400

added submodule
$ git cat-file -p 5d205c2e2ce63d8087b3b6644e3ac183cd49c644
100644 blob 30c9a7559a85f36bcedaabb8bdfaf43363966b85    .gitmodules
160000 commit 2122e5378b7940afae8e49ad9179c815c7711610  sub
```

That last line (`160000 commit ...`) shows the commit hash that `git` has recorded for your submodule.

If you were now to *clone* your repository with the submodule...

```
cd /tmp
git clone --recursive blah cloned-blah
```

You would find that `sub` is now not on a branch, because instead of a normal clone operation this checked out the explicit commit.

Comment: Aha... I see now.  I didn't realise that the original `git submodule add` leaves my local repository in a different state than if it were subsequently cloned.

I did a bit more testing with the way I cloned my repos, and I can see now that it is the act of **checking out** the submodule that detaches the HEAD (which makes sense).